# Create Tailwind Arbiturary Value Classes using SCSS

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, tailwind-css

Tailwind has arbitrary value classes in which you can enter your custom property value and it will set the **CSS** property to that value.

For example, if I want my **width** to be **37px** I can use the tailwind's arbitrary value class like this `w-[37px]`.

Is there a way to create the same utility class using **SCSS**?

Comment: I believe not, you can still use width directly or create some atom classes for different widths to use IMO, or use [template syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for in-line styles everywhere but I believe it's not gonna be a good idea you'd rather use Tailwind instead directly

Comment: Ok, I have customized utility classes built in scss according to my design. I only needed this for some use cases. If it's not possible then I guess I have to use the properties directly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No you can't.

This feature is only possible because tailwind compiles your code and generates css code dynamically. Pure SCSS doesn't have the resources for that.